# In SQL Server, how do you determine the number of rows per page?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, how do you determine the (average or expected) number of rows per page?

I know know how to determine the average and max row size, but I don't know how that relates to actual rows/page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

8060 bytes per page, 8 pages per extent...remember that if you row is 4040 bytes then you can only fit one row on the page

DBCC SHOWCONTIG will give you how many pages your table is using

Answer (score 1):

Pages are 8K in size including a 96byte header. So if you know the row size, you could make an estimate of how many rows would fit onto the data portion of a page.

Comment: Which row size should I used? The maximum or the average?

Comment: I know I'm late to this conversation but thought I'd throw my 2 cents in. I always keep my fields as small as possible without getting silly. Because of this, I use the maximum rather than the average. I would rather expect to fit 10 per page and wind up getting 20 rather than the other way around.